# What are cognates of "fuck" in other Indo-European languages?

Tags: etymology, indo-european, cognates, profanity

I am not asking for translations, but how the word itself is related to words in other languages and what those words have come to mean like how "shit" is related to "science". I would really appreciate it if you could explain the reasoning behind why the words evolved in different ways.

Comment: Why the down-votes?

Comment: Not my downvote, but considering the sheer number of Indo-European languages, I would guess it's because it's way too broad.

Comment: @tripleee: As emerges from the two answers, the number of cognates is actually very small.

Comment: @fdb: Probably, but arriving at that conclusion requires knowledge of many languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no really secure cognates outside the Germanic languages (see, e.g., [The Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuck) expressing the doubts about outer-Germanic relations). A maybe unexpected English cognate is *fidget*¹

One can try to relate the f-word with Latin *pugnus* "fist", *pugnare* "to fight" and German *fechten* "to fight, to fence", Greek *πυκτεύειν* "to fist-fight". With this, more cognates can be derived (e.g. German *Faust* "fist").

¹EDIT Unfortunately, deep links to a lemma ID do not work any longer with *woerterbuchnetz*. So here is the way to find it: Go to https://woerterbuchnetz.de, Click on DWB¹ (Deutsches Wörterbuch, 1st edition) and enter *ficken* into the search slit.

Answer (score 12):

From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> Probably cognate with Dutch fokken to mock (15th cent.), to strike
>   (1591), to fool, gull (1623), to beget children (1637), to have sexual
>   intercourse with (1657), to grow, cultivate (1772), Norwegian regional
>   fukka to copulate, Swedish regional fokka to copulate (compare Swedish
>   regional fock penis), further etymology uncertain: perhaps < an
>   Indo-European root meaning ‘to strike’ also shown by classical Latin
>   pugnus fist (see pugnacious adj.). Perhaps compare Old Icelandic fjúka
>   to be driven on, tossed by the wind, feykja to blow, drive away,
>   Middle High German fochen to hiss, to blow. Perhaps compare also
>   Middle High German ficken to rub, early modern German ficken to rub,
>   itch, scratch, German ficken to have sexual intercourse with (1558),
>   German regional ficken to rub, to make short fast movements, to hit
>   with rods, although the exact nature of any relationship is unclear.
>
> On the suggested Indo-European etymology (and for a suggestion that
>   the word was probably a strong verb during its earlier history in
>   English) see especially R. Lass ‘Four letters in search of an
>   etymology’ in Diachronica 12 (1995) 99–111.

Note the copious use of "probably", "perhaps" etc.

Comment: By the way, the cited article on "Four letters in search of an etymology" not only has a brilliant title; it is also a brilliant piece of linguistics.